# A problem occurred configuring project ':smart_auth'

Tags: flutter, build, firebase-authentication, geolocation, flutter-dependencies

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> 2
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':smart_auth' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Above problem occurs when we add pinput package into our project. But I didn't added smart_auth package anywhere in the project, but still getting error.
If I remove the pinput package ,it is working fine.

Flutter 3.3.10
Dart 2.18.6

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the code on an emulator you get the smart_auth error. It does not show the error on a real device. Seems to be a bug.